# Multiline regex does select too much or too few stuff

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I'm trying to write a regex to "parse" some kind of logfile. The structure looks like this:

```
2013-09-05 00:01:14.5726 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] New instance of service created.
2013-09-05 00:01:14.6038 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] 
---------------- [ Ping received ] -------------
CurrentPrincipel has Claims:
Claim Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name with Value: GROUP\User
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176895030-23737
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarygroupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-174895030-513
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176892330-513
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-1-0
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-32-545
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-2
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-11
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-15
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-326895030-16415
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-1732895030-31127
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176235030-12815
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176892330-12145
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176895430-31228
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176892330-16100
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-64-10

2013-09-05 00:01:15.0406 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] New instance of service created.
2013-09-05 00:01:15.0718 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] GetLangugesChanges invoked for rowVersion 1 and 8 clientChanges.
```

What I like to achieve with my regex is to get 4 matches for the log entries (each entry = 1 match). I tried the following regex but can't get the lines without the leading timestamp:

```
(^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(.|^|$)*(?=>^\d{4})*)
```

The regex is called like this:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(@"log.txt");
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(.|^|$)*(?=>^\d{4})*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("------");
}
```

And the output given is:

```
2013-09-05 00:01:14.5726 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] New instance of service created. ------
2013-09-05 00:01:14.6038 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim]  ------
2013-09-05 00:01:15.0406 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] New instance of service created. ------
2013-09-05 00:01:15.0718 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] GetLangugesChanges invoked for rowVersion 1 and 8 clientChanges.
------
```

The output expected would be:

```
2013-09-05 00:01:14.5726 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] New instance of service created.
------
2013-09-05 00:01:14.6038 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] 
---------------- [ Ping received ] -------------
CurrentPrincipel has Claims:
Claim Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name with Value: GROUP\User
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176895030-23737
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarygroupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-174895030-513
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176892330-513
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-1-0
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-32-545
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-2
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-11
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-15
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-326895030-16415
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-1732895030-31127
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176235030-12815
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176892330-12145
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176895430-31228
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-21-36134387-561137642-176892330-16100
Claim Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid with Value: S-1-5-64-10
------
2013-09-05 00:01:15.0406 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] New instance of service created.
------
2013-09-05 00:01:15.0718 WEB Info [n/a: UPN Claim] GetLangugesChanges invoked for rowVersion 1 and 8 clientChanges.
------
```

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to match everything between two dates (or the end of the file), like so:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*?(?=^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|(?!.))
```

Use this with `RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Another option is to split the string using regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string[] result = regex.Split(input);
```

Comment: That works as expected, thanks. It's `RegexOptions.Singleline` instead of `RegexOptions.SingleLine`. I fixed it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your question correctly this should help.

```
(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} )(.*)
```

Example:

```
 2013-09-05 00:01:14.6038 VSWEB04 Info [n/a: UPN Claim]
```

Matched:

```
VSWEB04 Info [n/a: UPN Claim]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's not exactly what I wanted. See my updated question with the expected output